# Local Database not working

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have working MVC5. i have created portal site its working server db connection after i have created local db connect local sql server its not connect db. 
server db connection using

```
Appseetings.config 

 <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <appSettings>

      <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
      <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
      <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
      <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
      <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />

      <add key="DefaultMembershipName" value="UserName" />

      <add key="SmtpServer" value="relay-hosting.secureserver.net" />
      <add key="SmtpPort" value="25" />
      <add key="UserId" value="thenna41@gmail.com" />
      <add key="Password" value="pixel@1990" />


      <add key="DefaultTheme" value="Theme1"/>
      <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
      <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
      <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
      <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
         <!--<add key="thenna" value="server=121.11.1.2;database=montage;user id=montage;password=pass;trusted_connection=false;"/>-->

          <!--<add key="thenna" value="server=DESKTOP-QD6A981\SQLEXPRESS;user id=montage;password=montage;trusted_connection=false;" />-->

          <add key="thenna" value="server=DESKTOP-QD6A981\SQLEXPRESS;trusted_connection=true;" />

          <add key="CustomAuthentication.LoginUrl" value="/Account/LogOn" />
          <add key="CustomAuthentication.Cookie.Name" value=".CUSTOM_AUTH" />
          <add key="CustomAuthentication.Cookie.Expiration" value="1" />
          <add key="CustomAuthentication.Cookie.Timeout" value="20" />

        </appSettings>
```

I have called local db config its not working

`key="thenna"` --> Used to read string from db connection

Appsettings Reader using to read thenna  key value

```
public class HomeSqlRepository : Repository
    {
        public string ConnectionString { get; set; } = AppSettingsReader.ReadString("thenna");
        const int MaxItemCount = 1000;
        public enum SqlExecuteType
        {
            Scalar, NonQuery, Reader
        }
        public async Task<string> ExecuteSqlAsync(string procname, SqlExecuteType executiontype, IDictionary<string, string> parameters)
        {
            string ret = "";

            using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(procname, sqlConn))
                {
                    sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in parameters)
                    {
                        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
                    }
                    sqlConn.Open();
                    if (executiontype == SqlExecuteType.Scalar)
                        ret = (await sqlCmd.ExecuteScalarAsync()).ToString();
                    else if (executiontype == SqlExecuteType.NonQuery)
                        ret = (await sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync()).ToString();
                    sqlConn.Close();
                }
            }

            return ret;
        }

        public T  GetItem<T>(string procname, IDictionary<string, object> parameters)
        {

            procname.ThrowIfNull();



            using (IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
              var result= db.Query<T>(sql: procname, param: BuildQueryParameter(parameters), commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
                return result.FirstOrDefault();
            }


        }
```

App settings Reader  using cloudconfirmationmanager 
 using Following Code

```
  public static class AppSettingsReader
    {
        public static string ReadString(string key)
        {
            try
            {
                return CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting(key).ToString();
            }
            catch(System.Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        public static int ReadInt(string key)
        {
            try
            {
                return int.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting(key).ToString());
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
}
```

where is reading value   i have created db local but  not working but when connect server its Working. what is mistake here ? thanks in advance

Comment: Not working doesn't describe your problem. Please add the exact error message received. (You don't go to your physician and tell him just that you are not feeling well, right?)

Comment: what is the exact error message and where in the code that error occurs ?

Comment: Potential answerers can't help you without being more specific as to what "not working" is.

Comment: No value throw return value null Null throw  Exception reference error i used  breakpoint.  one mor question azure configuration manager  how to change to read local sql db

Comment: Windows Azure Configuration manager Read only from server db key value . can not read local db key value. so local db return null value

Comment: I really hope for your sake that the "password" values you are using here are made up. I see IP addresses and email/password combinations.

Answer (score 0):

change your connection string to

```
<add key="thenna" value="Data Source=DESKTOP-QD6A981\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True" />
```

if this doesn't work, please share the error you are getting.